# How to solve this equation ? - Exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

[image]

How do i solve that equation algebraically ?

Thanks!

Comment: Most probably you don't. Equations like this very rarely have a closed form solution.

Comment: In which domain?

Answer (score 2):

IN THE CASE $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Firstly you can factor:

$2^x(x^2+2^x)=(x^2-2^x)(x^2+2^x)$, but  $x^2+2^x\neq0$ so we simplify:

$2^x=x^2-2^x$ and we obtain just:
$2^{x+1}=x^2$.

So you have to find zeroes of  $f(x)=2^{x+1}-x^2$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We have that $x=-1$ is a solution.

$f'(x)=\log(2)2^{x+1}-2x$, which is always positive (clearly it's positive for $x<0$), and it's not difficult to verify for $x>0$
So $f$ is monotonic and $-1$ is the only solution.

Comment: $x=-1$ is a solution.

Comment: $-1$ is an integer.  The OP didn't even specify real solutions...there are plenty of complex solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed x being a *natural* number

Comment: So you look for *complex* solution, maybe you could add that to your question

Answer (score 2):

If we divide both sides of the equation by $4^x$, we can rewrite it as

$${x^2\over2^x}+1=\left(x^2\over2^x\right)^2-1$$

If we now write $u=x^2/2^x$, we have a quadratic, $u+1=u^2-1$, or

$$u^2-u-2=(u-2)(u+1)=0$$

Now $x^2/2^x=-1$ clearly has no solution, since $x^2/2^x$ is always non-negative.  So we are left with $x^2/2^x=2$, or

$$x^2=2^{x+1}$$

A quick sketch of the parabola $y=x^2$ and the exponential curve $y=2^{x+1}$ shows these intersect at exactly one negative value of $x$, which, by inspection, turns out to be at $x=-1$.  A simple argument comparing parabolic to exponential growth (and/or a bit of calculus) shows there is no intersection for positive values of $x$.  Thus $x=-1$ is the only solution.